# Apply a function on an Hibernate projection property

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a Criteria query on Hibernate 4 which uses a projection list like this;

```
    Criteria c = getSession().createCriteria(Question.class);

    ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
    projectionList.add(Projections.property("id"), "id");
    projectionList.add(Projections.property("type"), "type");
```

Problem is, that **type** is an enumerated value and I have an helper class that maps generic enums to a resource string which I would like to call. ie:

```
resourceHelper.getEnumResource(QuestionType.xxxx);
```

Would it possible for that projection to call my helper method? The only solution I can think of is to add the method to the enum itself, but that would force me to @AutoWire an instance of MessageSource (I'm using Spring) to Enum which I think might be a bit of overkill.

Comment: Are you using DTO in this case?

Comment: yes sir. I'm using a DTO and a Transformers.aliasToBean() to map values.

Comment: can you show that DTO class?

Comment: It is just a POJO with properties named as the aliases in the projection List.

Comment: Idea is, in that DTO class create a property say `enumResource` with getter only (no setter) and in getter you can write a code to return `resourceHelper.getEnumResource(QuestionType.xxxx);` here `QuestionType.xxxx` will be the value of property that holds `type` in DTO.

Comment: If that is the only way convert your comment to na answer and i will accept it

Comment: M/ay be someone other (new comer) has done the task :) anyways that is the way I am talking about, hope it will help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as @Amogh said in comment, This is the best and correct way I feel. You have not posted your DTO code that's why its quite difficult to show in code format.

Doing this I consider that you are having property `questionType` in DTO class which stores value of `type` as per projection.

Add a property which will hold `EnumResource` like:

```
private EnumResource enumResource;
```

//only getter

```
public EnumResource getEnumResource()
{      
     return this.enumResource;     
}
```

And in the setter of `questionType` you already having code to set `this.questionType` just below of line of code add add following line which will set the value for enumResource:

```
this.enumResource = resourceHelper.getEnumResource(this.questionType);
```

Comment: Why you are checking `this.enumResource!=null` if it is returning `null`. You can say `return this.enumResource;` without any condition so that if it is null it will return null otherwise whatever the value.

Comment: @Amogh Oh yes, you're right. Sorry for bad code. I will edit.